# What's the difference between HTTPX and requests module in python that is causing this error

Tags: python, http, python-requests

Not much to say, I'm sending a request to some url. One HTTP Client returns 403, one succeds. No difference in headers. What else can be different?

```
>>> print(httpx.get(url).status_code)
200
>>> print(requests.get(url).status_code)
403
```

Answer (score 12):

My guess would be that the website is blocking requests from requests library.

### How is that possible?

With each request you are leaving behind [fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) of device that made it. This fingerprint amongst other information contains [user-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).

When you are doing requests with requests library by default user agent value is set to something like "python-requests/2.28.0" while for httpx library it's something like "python-httpx/0.23.0".

Based on information contained in your fingerprint website might choose to handle your request differently from others. For example returning error page instead of real content.

### But why?

Python is often used for [web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) and requests is one of the more popular libraries. Many people will choose to use it in their project. Because of that many websites choose to not serve real content to requests with "python-requests/*" user agent.

Because handling of requests costs money, websites are trying to serve content only to real people instead of [bots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_bot). Bot traffic also tends to be way bigger compared to real people. While some people just want to forbid 3rd parties to use their content in the ways they don't like or know about.

Httpx library is doing the same but it's not as wide-known as requests library so you'll find more websites which are not blocking such requests.

### Is it possible to bypass blocking?

Yes, there are many online resources about the topic. Just search for something like "avoid requests blocking".

Comment: OP has stated that there is no difference in headers between both requests (which includes the user-agent here). But honestly, they just are probably wrong. Without more details about both the requests, there is not much to investigate

Comment: The difference between was the SSL Ciphers Suites. The requests module implemented some Ciphers Suites that didn't work on that website. In some old version, I can't really recall, but I remember going through like 60 versions, checking every commit affecting the Cipher Suites change and turned out it was the problem.

Comment: @CharchitAgarwal In this case we've already checked the request headers via both http://httpbin.org/get and http://httpbingo.org/get, and they're absolutely identical with both `requests` and `httpx` if the User-Agent is set to the same value. Cookies were also accepted in both comparisons using `requests.Session()` and `httpx.Client()` respectively. As such, the theory of Cipher Suites being different deserves more investigation.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that the site here doesnt support http1.0 requests and only accepts http2.0 requests.
`httpx` supports http2.0